# LCP : page loading only part of the entire body

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system

I wanted to expose a solution that I found and understand if it is a monstrosity or a practice that can be right.

To largely solve the LCP problem I created a web page in php that loads only the first  contained in the body and then, once the page has been loaded, in javascript it loads the rest of the  of the page and puts them after the first one already loaded.

This solution to improve LCP seems useful to me but I have a problem because when I load plain html everything works very well but when I load a html which uses other javasccript for effects (fade in, fade out of elements on the page) the effects don't work.

From here I asked myself the doubt and then the question: is the proposed solution a monstrosity and therefore a road to be abandoned or is it a useful solution and therefore I have to study how to solve the subsequent bugs?
Thanks for your advice.

first load <div 1>
by javascript, on page load: load <div 2, 3, 4, etc>

Comment: LCP: Largest Contentful Paint

Comment: Make sure you run the JS code for the effects after all the content is loaded. An other way is to use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/1169519). If these won't help, please ask a case-specific question with a real code example.